# Can you leave and return to Switzerland if you have a Swiss residency permit?

Tags: switzerland

I'm currently in Switzerland for a short term study & have been given a Swiss Permit (that expires October).

Thing is: I have to return to my home country - for a short personal visit before returning to Switzerland. The travel is about a week long. Am I right in saying that my Swiss permit allows me to re-enter Switzerland without a visa ? My passport requires me to obtain a visa for a lot of countries.

Comment: what are your citizen?

Comment: Should be no problem. To make absolutely sure, could you tell us the exact type of permit you have (in French or German)? Specifically, we need to know what's written under “Art des Titels/Catégorie de titre” if it's a plastic card or the big letter on the cover if it's a booklet.

Comment: @Relaxed is there any category of Swiss residence permit that does not permit the bearer to leave and re-enter Switzerland?

Comment: @phoog Permit is awfully vague, the OP did not even use the word “residence”, I prefer to check. I have no reason to think it's the case here but I would generally expect a temporary document issued after applying for asylum to have such restrictions. In France, people who apply for a residence permit after a period of illegal stay (you can qualify if you have a child who is ill, if you worked in France for more than five years, etc.) also receive such a document while their application is processed. It's rare but they do exist, some distant relatives actually had one in the past.

Comment: (Technically, I think it's the case for all first applications for a residence permit but if you haven't stayed illegally before, you should generally be covered by a long-stay visa while your first application is being processed so you don't really care.)

Comment: @Relaxed mine is the plastic card under which for "Catégorie de titre" it says "Authorisation de courte durée (L)" and observation has a remark as "Séjour pour formation" or study purposes. 

The expiry of said L permit is at end October.

Comment: @Relaxed sorry for not being clear but mine's a permit 'L'

Comment: @user60759 It's perfectly fine then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may obviously leave and return to Switzerland as often as you want. All residency permits work as Schengen visas when it comes to entering and leaving the Schengen area.